# How can i directly add particular product to persistent cart in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am adding product from my mobile device and due to this everytime new session is generated in wp_sessions. and cart data is not added to the persistent cart in usermeta table.

Can you let me know how we can directly add product to current user persistent cart in usermeta?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress discourage usage of SESSION concepts.

I Would advice you to check [WoCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/) plugin architecture and internal working code, it uses wp_usermeta table to store persistence shopping cart.

Comment: Yes but actually i am adding product from mobile native app. 
And due to this everytime a new session_key is generated. 
i dont want to create new session_key eveytime add_to_cart is clicked.?

Comment: @parikhdeeshit i want store cart product from mobile device in usermeta table. have you found the solution?